# Powerquery xlsb files

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Good morning,
Is there a solution to import into powerquery excel files saved in XLSB format.

THANKS

I always stumbled on this problem, and apart from the solution which consists in opening the file, and saving it under *.xlsx, I did not find any other solution. But I think it's a shame since it's a MICROSOFT file type, and it's very practical considering the space saving it provides.
I've always come up against this problem, and apart from the solution, there is the VBA solution which reviews all the files and saves them in XLSX format, but it's a bit cumbersome

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ienihcrlzqw1cda/AADmKcIXGDUjFJhL0-vTessAa?dl=0

Comment: What is the issue? xlsb can be read just like xlsx, such as: Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Temp\Book1.xlsb"), null, true),

Comment: I post the error message returned by Excel when importing an xlsB file via PowerQuery,Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

Error Message:
Erreur

Stack Trace:


Stack Trace Message:
Erreur

Invocation Stack Trace:
Etc....
Etc....
Supports Premium Content:
True

Formulas:


section Section1;

shared Cycle_B01 = let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("Z:\Windows\Documents\Dropbox\clients Dropbox\Centre hospitalier de bretagne\2 révision\2022\Fecxtools 140922\Cycle_B01.xlsb"), null, true)
in
    Source;

Comment: Sorry, I cannot debug your specific filepath or set up. Powerquery does read in xlsb

Comment: I post the error message returned by Excel when importing an xlsb file via PowerQuery.The same, saved in XLSM format is easily opened by powerquery. There is a problem with XLSB. Either the files are open, but with an extremely long processing time, or they crash PowerQuery ==error report ==Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)
Error Message:
Etc....
Formulas:
section Section1;
shared Cycle_B01 = let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("Z:\Windows\Documents\Dropbox\clients Dropbox\Centre hospitalier de bretagne\2 révision\2022\Fecxtools 140922\Cycle_B01.xlsb"), null, true)
in
    Source;

Comment: here is the dropbox link with the two xlsb and xlsm files, from which I removed a lot of "confidential" sheets

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ienihcrlzqw1cda/AADmKcIXGDUjFJhL0-vTessAa?dl=0

Comment: I'm sure someone will take a look. I dont open other peoples files for security reasons